# Is it possible to make an image as small as possible while still filling its container, and keeping its aspect ratio?

Tags: html, image, css

I have a container of a given size, and I have an image inside it. I want the image to expand to either 100% height or 100% width, depending on whichever comes last, and I want it to keep its aspect ratio, so anything sticking on over the container is cropped off. If it's cropped on the sides, I'd also like it to be centered.

So to be clear, if it's a very wide picture, it would have `height: 100%`, and if it's a very tall picture, it would have `width: 100%`.

For example, here's the container and the image, with is neither sized correctly, nor centered:

https://jsfiddle.net/y5px1ch9/1/

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f1/S%C3%A4ugende_H%C3%BCndin.JPG/800px-S%C3%A4ugende_H%C3%BCndin.JPG" class="picture">
</div>


.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  left: 40%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
.picture {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Anyone know if this is possible to do with CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have a fixed size wrapper, and as `object-fit` does not have that good browser support, I suggest you use `background`/`background-size` on the wrapper

Now, by setting its position, you control where it should get cropped. In below sample I used `left top`, which means it crops at right/bottom, and in your case, you might want `center center`, which will crop equally top/bottom or left/right, based on which of the two overflows.

Updated based on a comment

One can also set the image source in the markup, just how one do with the `img`, here done by setting `background-image: url()` inline.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  left: 40%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left top;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f1/S%C3%A4ugende_H%C3%BCndin.JPG/800px-S%C3%A4ugende_H%C3%BCndin.JPG)">
</div>
```

---

And here is the version using `object-fit`

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  left: 40%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.picture {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: left top;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f1/S%C3%A4ugende_H%C3%BCndin.JPG/800px-S%C3%A4ugende_H%C3%BCndin.JPG" class="picture">
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good solution, the only problem is that the picture is dynamically loaded, and I don't think its possible to dynamically load images into CSS.

Comment: @JoeMorano No problem... will update my answer in a sec

Comment: @JoeMorano Updated with a solution for that

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but you have to know the aspect ratio beforehand, knowing this you can reserve space for the image

```css
div {
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

div::after {
  padding-top: 56.25%; /* percentage of containing block _width_ */
  display: block;
  content: '';
}

div img {
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    bottom: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
    right: -9999px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200x300"/>
</div>
```

The main trick is the **padding-top: 56.25%;**... the aspect ratio

Answer (score 0):

If you define the image as a background-image, then you can use `background-size: contain` - this does what you want:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  left: 40%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f1/S%C3%A4ugende_H%C3%BCndin.JPG/800px-S%C3%A4ugende_H%C3%BCndin.JPG) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
</div>
```

Comment: @LGSon ah, I saw your answer, but it looked much more complicated than what I had in mind (just compare the amount code there is in your and in my answer (?))

Comment: If you read OP's comment below my answer you'll see why... and I kept OP's sample code from the fiddle (will delete it now so it does not confuse more users)

Comment: And if you still plan to keep your answer, OP asks for _as small as possible while still **filling** its container_, which means `cover`, not `contain`

Comment: @ ahh - you see, there's another difference between our answers! *I* think that this actually calls for `contain`, not `cover`. We'll see what the OP will say about it...

Comment: Did you also miss _so anything sticking on over the container is cropped off_? ... and you still think it is `contain`?

Comment: @Johannes My apologies, I was looking for 'cover', but I think I used confusing phrasing. I said "100% height or 100% width, whichever comes first" when I should have said "whichever comes last".

Answer (score 0):

try this

**vertical**

```
.picture {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
      width: auto;
      margin: auto;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      background-position: center;
    }
```

**horizontal**

```
.picture {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      margin: auto;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      background-position: center;
    }
```

[jsfiddle horizontal case](https://jsfiddle.net/y5px1ch9/4/)

[jsfiddle vertical case](https://jsfiddle.net/y5px1ch9/5/)

Answer (score 0):

please add height property auto and image width in percentage %, in this property you can manage aspect ratio,

```
width:50%, 
height:auto,
```